# CodeIgniter 3 MY_Loader

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm using CodeIgniter 3 with HMVC.

In CI2, I could load a model and call functions on one line like this:

```
$this->load->model('mymodule/mymodule_model')->some_function();
```

But CI3 throws an error and I have to load the model on a separate line.

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method MY_Loader::some_function() in
```

This works:

```
$this->load->model('mymodule/mymodule_model');
$this->mymodule_model->some_function();
```

Is this normal behavior or is something misconfigured with CI3 / HMVC?

Comment: Since loading/calling on one line is not documented AFAIK, I'd say it's not official usage and was likely fixed in CI 3.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you chain model calls in CodeIgniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14881110/can-you-chain-model-calls-in-codeigniter)